# Create C string copy function in assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to emulate the C string copy command in assembly. I am passing the array called A to an .asm file and want to return it as the array called B, and then print it as you can see below. I am not sure how to do this. I am trying to pull the value off the stack with "MOV EDX,[EBP+4];", but i dont know how i can return this as a variable to my C file.

Main.c

```
int main()
{
    char A[] = "abcdef";
    char B[100];
    strcopyx(B,A,sizeof(B));
    printf("%s\n",B);
    return sieve();
}
```

cstringlib.asm

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096                 
n=550
.data
    PUBLIC _strcopyx
    charArray DWORD 4 DUP(?)
.code

_strcopyx  PROC
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP

MOV EDX,[EBP+4];get A ??

mov eax, 0

POP EBP
ret
_strcopyx ENDP
END
```

Comment: This depends on the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) used. Are you compiling for Windows, Linux, Mac, or some other platform? Are you sure you're compiling for 32-bit mode (if not, you need to use `RDX` etc. to store pointers, not `EDX`)?

Comment: Just as you know that function parameters are accessible through the stack, that same source (textbook? lesson?) should have told you how a result is returned. It's actually fairly obvious.

Comment: You need to learn about calling convention adn ABI-s.  You can experiment with the godbolt to see how it is done by the compiler: https://godbolt.org/g/QzzpkB

Comment: @Daniel H Yeah this is x86 Assembly on Windows

Comment: @usr2564301  I have pass individual values and pull them off the stack. For example, if i pass an integer, i can easily find it on the stack. I cant seem to figure out how to pull a character array off the stack, none of the values of that array are showing up in memory.

Comment: @Some_Dude The `strcopy` function takes a character *pointer*, not a character *array*; the characters themselves aren't on the stack (same with the return value). I believe the default calling convention for Windows x86 is [`stdcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall), where the return pointer goes in `EAX`.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 That only helps you learn about the calling convention the Compiler Explorer compiles use, not whatever's necessary on your system. You could add `__attribute__((stdcall))` or whatever to the function, but if you know which calling convention you want it's probably easier just to look up the rules for that.

Comment: @DanielH `__attribute__((stdcall))` is the 386 only attribute and to be honest as I see is ignored on some ABIs